# Запоминать нажатие на кнопки Telebot python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

При нажатии `inline` кнопок бот каждый раз заново вызывает функцию внутри метода, а как я могу записывать нажаты ли ранее кнопки?

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callBack(call):
    try:
        if call.data == 'yes':
            murkup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("1", callback_data='yes1')
            button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("2", callback_data='yes2')
            button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("3", callback_data='yes3')
            button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("4", callback_data='yes4')
            button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("5", callback_data='yes5')
            murkup.add(button1, button2, button3, button4, button5)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Да, я так и думал. Разбираем роли ",
                             reply_markup=murkup)
        elif call.data == 'yes1':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>КЕРРИ</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
        elif call.data == 'yes2':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>МИДЕР</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
        elif call.data == 'yes3':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>ХАРДЛАЙНЕР</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
        elif call.data == 'yes4':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>РОУМЕР</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
        elif call.data == 'yes5':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>САППОРТ</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
        elif call.data == 'no':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Нет? А ты уверен  ?")
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Если я пропишу в каждом if по переменной и запишу в неё True, то после следующего нажатия на кнопку всё обнулиться.

Comment: Вам нужна база данных, в ней для текущего user.id и chat.id сохраняйте значение. Для начала это можно в виде глобального контейнера сделать (список или словарь), а как отработаете код с ним, перепишите на работу с бд

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сделать список и при нажатии проверять есть ли в списке, если нет то добавляешь,  если есть то пишешь что занято.

примерно вот так

```
roles = []
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callBack(call):
    try:
        if call.data == 'yes':
            murkup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("1", callback_data='yes1')
            button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("2", callback_data='yes2')
            button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("3", callback_data='yes3')
            button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("4", callback_data='yes4')
            button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("5", callback_data='yes5')
            murkup.add(button1, button2, button3, button4, button5)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Да, я так и думал. Разбираем роли ",
                             reply_markup=murkup)
        elif call.data == 'yes1':
            if roles.count('yes1') > 0:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>КЕРРИ</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
            else:
                roles.append('yes1')
        elif call.data == 'yes2':
            if roles.count('yes2') > 0:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>МИДЕР</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
            else:
                roles.append('yes2')
        elif call.data == 'yes3':
            if roles.count('yes3') > 0:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>ХАРДЛАЙНЕР</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
            else:
                roles.append('yes3')
        elif call.data == 'yes4':
            if roles.count('yes4') > 0:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>РОУМЕР</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
            else:
                roles.append('yes4')
        elif call.data == 'yes5':
            if roles.count('yes5') > 0:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Роль <b>САППОРТ</b> занята {0.first_name}".format(call.from_user),
                             parse_mode="html")
            else:
                roles.append('yes5')
        elif call.data == 'no':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Нет? А ты уверен  ?")
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```